# Mobile First - Where can we change the hostname in the installation of Mobile First/Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am going to upgrade the version from 7.0.0 to 8.0.0 of Mobile First and before I proceed, I wanted to update the hostname in the installation(if any) on my cloned server so that it wouldn't affect the services and applications on active server.

Please help me in this.

Comment: You are setting up 8.0 on a different server and hence the hostname change? What exactly are you cloning? 
Note that there is no direct upgrade path from 7.0 -> 8.0. You have to install it fresh

Comment: Hello 
First of all thanks for your reply.

I am not installing a new one, as a requirement is to upgrade from 7.0 --> 8.0 version. 
But, I want to make a clone of an active server so that I could do some tests(and it wouldn't affect the current setup on active server where applications are running).
It would be good, if you could tell me how can I update the hostname in a cloned server so I would be able to start/stop the services/applications of Mobile First.

Comment: @VivinK
Hello First of all thanks for your reply. I am not installing a new one, as a requirement is to upgrade from 7.0 --> 8.0 version. But, I want to make a clone of an active server so that I could do some tests(and it wouldn't affect the current setup on active server where applications are running). It would be good, if you could tell me how can I update the hostname in a cloned server so I would be able to start/stop the services/applications of Mobile First.

Comment: Points to note : 1) There is no direct upgrade path from 7.0 -> 8.0 . That is, you cannot do an in-place upgrade of a 7.0 MFP server to 8.0. This needs to be done by installing 8.0 separately. 
2) The JVM on which MFP server is installed binds to and takes the hostnames/IP from the underlying system. MFP server uses those .'

Comment: @VivinK Thank you so much for your response, VivinK. I would like to ask few questions regarding configuration/installation:
1) How could we do clustering for App1 and App2 servers
2) Where can we find the applications deployed in MF( I mean, there should be some servers inside the MF configuration, do you have any idea)
3) And, as per the installation...its mentioned there Java version should be up to date i.e. 7 but I didn't find the version of Java in MF. I was able to find the version of Java for WAS...is it same? I have a doubt here.